# Two or three letter initials in bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

In my bibliography, I need to abreviate first names keeping digraphs and trigraphs.

- John should be abreviated as J.
- Clare should be abreviated as Cl.
- Charles should be abreviated as Ch.
- Christine should be abreviated as Chr.
- Philippe should be abreviated as Ph.
- etc.

The solution is to modify the first name in the bibliographical data from

> Charles

to

> {\relax Ch}arles

The following example uses the `\DeclareSourcemap` customization macro in Biblatex to change `Charles` to `{\relax Ch}arles` but I'm looking for a more generic solution that would automatically modify all first names starting with two or three consonants.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Book1,
  author = {Doe, Charles},
  title  = {An Important Book},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2012},
}
@book{Book2,
  author = {Doe, Charlotte},
  title  = {Another Important Book},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2014},
}
@book{Book3,
  author = {Smith, Theodore},
  title  = {A very Important Book},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose,firstinits=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
    \step[fieldsource=author, 
            match={Charles},
            replace=\regexp{\{\\relax \x20Ch\}arles}]
  }
 }
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{Book1}

\cite{Book2}

\cite{Book3}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: See the code used in class `droit-fr`.

Comment: @ienissei That sounds like a nice answer to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible starting point would be to use the code Yves de Saint-Pern wrote in class [droit-fr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/droit-fr), which I am translating below.

> **EDIT :** The regular expressions provided here catch last names as well, which may cause issues outside Biblatex, for instance in indexes done with `imakeidx`. A tentative solution to this problem is [provided here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331040/10119).

You can use it in a `biber.conf` file or include it in your `.bbx`.

Some languages may require additional regex patterns for first names, but they are pretty straightforward to add.

```
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
        % Author field
      \step[fieldsource=author,%
        match={\regexp{\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))(\S*,)}},%
        replace={\regexp{\{$1\}$3}}]% Protect last names (first last)
      \step[fieldsource=author,%
        match={\regexp{([^,]\s)\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))}},%
        replace={\regexp{$1\{$2\}}}]% Protect last names (last, first)
      \step[fieldsource=author,%
        match={\regexp{\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))([^\}])}},%
        replace={\regexp{\{\\relax\{\}$1\}$3}}]% Insert \relax after abbreviating
      % Editor field
      \step[fieldsource=editor,%
        match={\regexp{\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))(\S*,)}},%
        replace={\regexp{\{$1\}$3}}]% Protect last names (first last)
      \step[fieldsource=editor,%
        match={\regexp{([^,]\s)\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))}},%
        replace={\regexp{$1\{$2\}}}]% Protect last names (last, first)
      \step[fieldsource=editor,%
        match={\regexp{\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))([^\}])}},%
        replace={\regexp{\{\\relax\{\}$1\}$3}}]% Insert \relax after abbreviating
}}}%
```

As far as the regular expressions are concerned, I am no expert but I would hazard that the expression means this:

`\b(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))(\S*,)`

A word (`\b`) that starts with (`\S*` means: ends with any number of non-space characters): `Chr` (Chris) or `Ch` (Charles) or `Th` (Thomas) or `Ph` (Philippe), or any combination that starts with a consonant (the `[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ` part is a set of ranges: letters B to D, F to H, J to N, P to T, V to X, Z) followed by `l` or `r` (Bruno or Claire would fall within that category).

Comment: Thank you. I found https://github.com/ienissei/frenchlaw/ on your github how is that related to `droit-fr`, if you don't mind me asking? I'm not great with RegEx, so I would really appreciate an explanation if you can find the time. I would be especially interested in the `[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]` bit.

Comment: Class `droit-fr` is meant for writing french dissertations in legal studies, and I am working on a very similar project (by coincidence more than by design, as I started with it before this class was published). It was updated lately and I saw the feature on the log.

Comment: @moewe – Added the explanation

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you also for the explanation, I now noticed I had failed to see the `(l|r)` after the `[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]` bit.

Comment: @ienissei how can this only be applied to first names - and not to last names? see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330971/98739

Comment: @LukasCB Commenting under your question.

Comment: How can I get it work only for `Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|St` ?

Comment: @LukasCB Just remove the rest of the string. Change: `(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ](l|r))` to `(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|St)`

Comment: @ienissei thanks. I realized that `()`(before `(l|r)` is important to keep, otherwise the first letter after `Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|St` will be omitted; correct:`(Chr|Ch|Th|Ph|St)()`

Comment: @LukasCB Yes, because the replacement string looks for three groups, which are the text between `()`, so you could also change `$3` to `$2` for the same result.