# Abbreviate first names with multiple letters with biblatex: {\relax Ch}arles not working

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber

There are quite a few posts on this site that deal with the problem of abbreviating names in the bibliography to two letters, for instance Charles to Ch. The suggested solutions include using the [\relax command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422938/two-or-three-letter-initials-in-bibliography-with-biblatex-again), either manual or [automated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297489/how-to-abbreviate-first-names-with-multiple-letters-using-biblatex) using source maps, or by defining a new commands such as [\newcommand{\Ch}{Ch}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26346/21294).

However, when I try to implement the first solution myself I do not get the desired results. Also the option with the new command does not work and keeps giving me nesting errors for some reason.

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Book1,
  author = {Doe, {\relax Ph}ilippe},
  title  = {An Important Book},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose,giveninits=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge the only solution that works properly with `biblatex` (and Biber) is the extended name format. Usage of the extended name format for this job is shown in the MWE of the question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422938/35864 my answer there contains a kludge to automate this that I do not recommend.

Comment: Thank you! I just came across your nice solution myself too, I don't know why I missed it before.

Comment: Can we close this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422938/35864 or do you need an answer? If you need an answer, what should it be about that hasn't been addressed by the linked discussion.

Comment: It can be closed and my apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: No need to apologise. It's always easier to find the duplicate if you also know the answer and the search terms are somewhat generic here.