# How to preserve author's initials from being abbreviated

Tags: bibtex

Some names should be abbreviated using not one but two characters, e. g. "Yuri Gagarin" => "Gagarin, Yu."
But if I specify

```
author = "Gagarin, Yu."
```

or even

```
author = "Gagarin, {Yu.}"
```

bibtex nevertheless abbreviate it as "Gagarin, Y.", with only one character.
How this can be corrected?

Compilable example, as requested in comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{pi,
  author = {Gagarin, Yu.},
  title  = {Everything is flying to 3.14},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
The rifle is a festivity\cite{pi}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bibliographystyle do you use? Can you show us a short compilable code building your bibliography? Do not forget to add an complete bib entry to your question ...

Comment: `author = "Gagarin, {\relax Yu}ri"` is the standard trick, which should work with BibTeX styles that abbreviate first names. If you use `biblatex` you need another approach.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, seems working! I use `bibtex`, but `biblatex` solution is still welcome

Comment: For BibTeX this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26332/35864. For `biblatex` we have https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422938/35864