# The multi-letter initial trick {\relax Ch}arles doesn't work in biblatex with biber anymore

Tags: biblatex, biber

The code below used to trick `biblatex` into assuming that the name `Charles` should be abbreviated as `Ch` (and not as one letter `C.`). It still happily works if I replace the backend from `biber` to `bibtex`, but emits `C.` if it's used as it is.

I've tested it on more or less up-to date TeXLive 2020. On the latest TeXLive 2019 it segfaults biber (!). On fairly old TeXLive 2015 it works as supposed to.

Is there any way to create multi-letter initials using the currrent TeXLive and biber?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author={Doe, {\relax Ch}arles},
  title={Some Article Title},
  journal={Some Journal},
  volume={1},
  year={2020}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422938/35864. This hasn't worked for a long time.

Comment: Right! I've overlooked that question. So, I can create a sourcemap which would process `{\relax Ch}arles` by biber, and it'll be happily ignored by bibtex. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the extended input method:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ch-init.bib}
@article{key,
  author={given=Charles, given-i={Ch}, family=Doe},
  title={Some Article Title},
  journal={Some Journal},
  volume={1},
  year={2020}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ch-init.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{filecontents}` is redundant; also `uniquename=init` is needed to avoid a warning (`biblatex` will set it anyway).

Comment: @egreg thanks, I still overlook filecontents ;-).

Comment: Nice! But totally not compatible with bibtex. So I can't use the same bib database with different backends...

Comment: The bib files aren't completely compatible anyway.

Comment: True, but so far I've managed to use only common fields.

Comment: you could add both fields to the entry: `author-biblatex={family=Doe, given=Charles,given-i={Ch}},
  author={Doe, {\relax Ch}arles},`  and then use a sourcemap that maps author-biblatex to author.